# MySQL extension not working in GeoServer 2.19.3

Tags: mysql-connector, geoserver

I downloaded the MySQL extension for GeoServer but the option for adding a MySQL database as a new store in GeoServer is not displayed. There are no issues reported in the log after restarting GeoServer.

My GeoServer version: 2.19.3

MySQL extension: https://phoenixnap.dl.sourceforge.net/project/geoserver/GeoServer/2.19.3/extensions/geoserver-2.19.3-mysql-plugin.zip

I copied the zip archive contents to /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.73/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib

I also modified the ownership of each file in the archive
to tomcat:chown -R tomcat:tomcat

I restarted GeoServer.

The log details can be found here: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AoHzL3uXbH31izDQWgrzDijr6uLY?e=8zeU8i

Any suggestions would be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I turned on the developer logging and attached the log output after restarting GeoServer in the above query. I don't see anything that indicates an issue with the MySQL extension.

Comment: You are missing the start of the log file (which is probably where your problem is)

Comment: Thanks for checking. I restarted GeoServer and here is the log:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AoHzL3uXbH31izHBkteG7_G-Ys3B?e=4yPpsQ

Comment: I can't see any reference to mysql are you sure you installed it in this instance of GeoServer?

Comment: I'll take a closer look but these are the extensions for MySQL:   
    root@eb366bbb8247:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.73/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib# ls *my*
   
    geoserver-2.19.3-mysql-plugin.zip  gt-jdbc-mysql-25.3.jar  mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar  mysql-readme.txt

Comment: I updated GeoServer to version 2.20.1 and the MySQL extension now appears to work with the option to add a MySQL store. I'm not sure what the issue was with 2.19.3.